# How Can i One side black in website header through HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: ****]

how can one side black with some side box-shadow look like an image through HTML and CSS??

Advanced thanks and love.

Comment: Use a div with a black gradient that goes from `opacity: 1;` to `opacity: 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question, you meant like below image, right?

[image]

So code for that,

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="section">
    <h1>Pushpa - The Rise</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  margin: 0;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center;
  background: #10151e;
}

.image{
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 5%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(16, 21, 30, 1),rgba(16, 21, 30, 0.95), rgba(16, 21, 30, 0.25), rgba(16, 21, 30, 0.2)), url('https://www.sify.com/uploads/Pushpa_vd0m26dcijffe.jpg');
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.section{
  flex: 1;
}

.image h1{
  color:white;
  padding-top:5%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

Feel free to ask if there any issue :)

Comment: Perfectly I understand, lots of love and thanks from my top heart.

Comment: @MR.Shohel It's pleasure to help you. If the answer is correct, can you mark as it correct please?

Comment: done brother. thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### To give this effect use background image, z-index, position property

- `background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black 45%, transparent 100%);`
  *Which gives that one side black effect and transparent on the image side.*

> For Image

- `position: absolute;`  *This allows you to position the element at the right even if the width of that background-image is 100%*

> For outerdiv

- `position: relative;`  *This property won't let the image get outside the outerdiv area*

> For image

- `z-index: -1;`  *This pushes back the image and pull the background at the front*

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black 45%, transparent 100%);
   z-index: 10;
}

.outerdiv{
  position: relative;
}

h1{
  color: white;
  font-family: youtube sans, montserrat;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0px 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
    float: right;
  z-index: -1;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
}

p{
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerdiv">
<div>
  <h1>
    Pushpa: The Rise (Telugu)
  </h1>
  <p>Pushpa Raj (Allu Arjun) a coolie, volunteers to smuggle red sanders, a rare wood that only grows in Andhra, with the help of novel ideas to smuggle the red sanders. Pushpa quickly becomes leader of red sanders smuggling network. While Pushpa is at his prime, a ruthless police officer Bhanwar Singh Shekhawat (Fahadh Faasil) takes charge as SP and ridicules Pushpa for his lineage.
</p>
</div>
<img src="https://akm-img-a-in.tosshub.com/businesstoday/images/story/202112/pushpaa-sixteen_nine.jpeg?size=948:533">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Huzafia, perfectly I understand. this helps me to better understand.